# Measure TLB Size

Tags: measurement

Is there a tool that will measure the size of my TLB for me? Or some sort of scripting approach I can take to estimate it?

Comment: Why not just look it up? It's in CPUID too.

Answer (score 1):

Chris s. has it right, you can probably just check the docs for the processor in question, especially if its an x86 processor. If for some reason you can't do this you can probably calculate it, I believe that lmbench can do this.

Answer (score 1):

As the question was about *measuring* the size of the TLB, not *querying* it, [the tlb test of lmbench](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/tlb.8.html) may be interesting. lmbench performs a set of micro benchmarks including a test that measures the TLB.